# invalid opcode error on invoking firefox driiver in selenium c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I am running my selenium script on amazon work space, scripting language using is c#

when i run my script in visual studio i got a error popup with message "**installer corrupted:invalid opcode**" . my script run properly but each time Firefox driver instance triggered this popup also appear

Below is my code used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Automation
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Loginpage
    {
        private FirefoxDriver driver;

        private string baseURL;

        public Loginpage() { }

        [SetUp]
        public void LoadDriver()
        {

          Console.WriteLine("SetUp");
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          baseURL = "https://google.com";


        }

        [Test]
        public void Login()
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void UnloadDriver()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TearDown");
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Issue got solved , uninstalled the Firefox and deleted Mozilla related folders and files and reinstalled the Firefox.